# probability of obtaining two even numbers throwing three dice

Tags: probability, dice

I have this problem from a text book, and the answer it gives for that probability is $\frac{25}{108}$.

I assumed that they are refering to the probability of obtaining two even and an odd. I created the sample space and counted all the points with two even and an odd using R since I also don't know how to use combinatorics for this case. I have obtained 81 so I suppose that the probability is $\frac{81}{216}=\frac{3}{8}$.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you print the problem exactly as it appears, with no edits?  The proposed answer, $\frac {25}{108}$, is hard to understand.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! Very strange; even if the book means "at least two even numbers", the given answer would be wrong. Notice that your answer $\frac{81}{216}$ can be simplified to $\frac{3}{8}$

Comment: Purely informational: "Dice" is the plural form, "die" is the singular. So one speaks of "rolling one die" or "rolling several dice". There is no such form "dices" of this word. (Sort of like "mouse" vs "mice", but not "mices".)

Comment: Ha ha, thank you for the clarification, English is not my mother tongue and I constructed the plural like we did in spanish. I'm sorry for my careless grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is wrong and you are right!   To confirm:...

If you roll one fair dice you will obtain an even result with a probability of $1/2$.

If you roll three fair die, you will obtain two consecutive even results, then an odd result with a probability of $1/2^3$.

There are three such arrangements which yeild a result of two even *and* one odd, and they are all equally probable.   Thus the probability for obtaining two even and one odd result is $3/8$, which **is** also $81/216$.

---

However, there is an additional arrangement which is a result of three even numbers, which has the same probability as the other three arrangements.   So the probability for *at least* two even results is $4/8$, $108/216$, or $1/2$.

To confirm the result, hindsight shows that there is a equal probability for obtaining *at least two even results* as there is for obtaining *at least two odd results*, and that these events are exclusive and exhaustive.

---

*Neither* answer is $25/108$, nor should they be.

Answer (score 0):

That looks right: you have 3 possibilities for each even number, and 3 for odd, and finally 3 possible dice to be the odd one. So that's 81. You are correct!

Also, notice that likewise you have 81 possibilities to get 1 even and 2 odd.

And you have 27 options for 3 even numbers, and also 27 for 3 odd ones.

Total: 27+81+81+27=216.  Which is the whole space. So that's further confirmation you're doing this all ok!

Answer (score 0):

In dice, we have half of the numbers odd and the other half of the even, which means that the probability of the odd numbers is ½ as well as the even
numbers. The possiblethrows are OEE EEOand EOE, so we have 3 possible throws.

So the probability will be equal to $ \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot 3 = \frac{3}{8}$.
or you can find the problem using the tables by finding all the possible tosses which are 216 and the tosses which are 1 odd and 2 even will be 81 which again gives the probability $\frac{3}{8}$ .